# Validate XML against XSD with custom validations

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Normally there is a standard way how to validate XML against XSD schema in Java, but I need to have more sophisticated validation, for example validation for **Zip Postal Code** which ensure that such ZIP really exists. Therefore I need some kind of customizable Validator to which I will define rule like: (sorry for triviality)

```
if( validationType.equals("ZipPostalCode") {
  com.fuu.validations.Address.zipPostalCode( innerText );   
}
```

What is the most straightforward way to achieve such custom validations in Java with XSD and some customisable validator library?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Saxon as your schema processor, then you can use XSD 1.1 assertions that invoke external Java methods:

```
<xs:simpleType name="zipCode" base="xs:string">
  <xs:assertion test="ext:isValidZipCode($value)" xmlns:ext="java:com.fuu.validations.Address"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: That's better that nothing but Saxon is not free :/ I'm surprised there isn't any standard solution to do what I want.

Comment: A lot of free XML software appeared between 1999 and 2003 but with no revenue stream, the developers ran out of money, so by and large, only the commercial products continued with new developments. You shouldn't be surprised.